# Deployed certificate to Personal store using GPO

Tags: group-policy, ssl-certificate, certificate, client-certificate

I am trying to find a user GPO to install a certificate in the personal store (this is a browser certificate and if installed in other stores it won't work so it has to be installed in the Personal store). I found a couple of GPOs but apparently none of them has to option to place the certificate in the Personal store.

Any ideas / hints how can I achieve this? I don't want to install the certificate manually since we have a lot of users and even worse they are changing workstations so each time a user logs in another computer we would have to manually install the certificate.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'browser certificate'? Do you have any interest in trusting the root issuing authority?

Comment: Basically this is a certificate that allows users to log into a specific website.  Once they press the login button of this site the certificate is prompted (if installed correctly in the personal store).